# adding more than one list item into List at a time when the items are generated dynamically (using NAPA)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, provider-hosted-app, napa

I am using the below code to insert an item into the list.

```
  function createitem() {
var selectListBox = document.getElementById("txtFormName");
var selectedListTitle = selectListBox.value;
var selectedList = web.get_lists().getByTitle(selectedListTitle);

var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var newItem = selectedList.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);

newItem.set_item('Title','abc');
newItem.update();
context.load(newItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(onItemCreationSuccess, onItemCreationFail);
```

}

Its working fine.
Now I want to use

```
    newItem.set_item('Title1','def');
    newItem.set_item('Title2','xyz');
    .
    .
    .
    and so on
```

in loop for more than one item in the same row to insert.
How can i achieve that. kindly guide.

Comment: Are you asking how to insert the same item multiple times?

Comment: @AmalHashim no. field name and value both will be different. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop as follows

```
var selectListBox = document.getElementById("txtFormName");
var selectedListTitle = selectListBox.value;
var selectedList = web.get_lists().getByTitle(selectedListTitle);

for(var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newItem = selectedList.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);
    newItem.set_item('Title' + index.toString(),'abc'+ index.toString());
    newItem.update();
}

context.load(selectedList);
context.executeQueryAsync(onItemCreationSuccess, onItemCreationFail);
```

Comment: Thanx Amal. Exactly what I needed. Just one thing: var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var newItem = selectedList.addItem(listItemCreationInfo); will be above the for loop. :) cheers